# Python Dash - how to pass parameters in @app.callback

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to create a Dash example that could make use of live updates by using the documentation here: https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates

In the code there is a key part which allows the app.call back to know what the input and output is:

```
@app.callback(Output('live-update-text', 'children'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')
```

This works well for one component, however if say I have five different data sets to update (all using the same logic), then I would naturally hope to have the @app.callback to be passed in dynamically like a function parameter. i.e., ideally if I have 5 output I can do:

```
@app.callback(Output('live-update-text-MyParam', 'children'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')
```

and then I can call it by using myParam = 1/2/3/4/5.

Is it possible?

**UPDATE 20220105**: Based on @coralvanda and @EricLavault's suggestion this is what I came up with:

```
def updateGraphsAndData(output, input):
    @app.callback([output['text'],
                   output['graph']],
                  [input['n_intervals'],input['name']])
    def updateGraphAndMetricForEach(n, name):
        return update_metrics(name), update_graph_live(name)

for param in lstParams:
    updateGraphsAndData(output={'text':Output(f'live-update-text-{param}','children'),'graph':Output(f'live-update-graph-{param}','figure')},
                        input={'n_intervals':Input(f'interval-component-{param}','n_intervals'),'name':Input(param, 'value')})
```

I am trying to update both the graph and the text in one shot and the update_metrics is the update text part (returns a list of html.Span() and .Br()s) and the update_graph_live returns a go.Figure object).

However when I run this the page does not return any chart nor text to be updated, and clicking on the "callback" on the bottom right part, I see the children is pointed to null (even though I can see it is passed in as 'live-update-text-PARAM' and I can confirm update_metrics for valid inputs of name).

Is there still any place I am missing something?

**UPDATE 20220106**: Portion of app.layout code:

```
dbc.Col([
                html.Div(id=f'live-update-text-{param1}'),
                dcc.Graph(id=f'live-update-graph-{param1}'),
                dcc.Interval(
                id=f'interval-component-{param1}',
                interval=2*1000, # in milliseconds
                n_intervals=0
                ),
            html.Hr(),
            ], width={'size': 4, 'offset': 0, 'order': 1}),
```

And then this repeated for param1/param2/param3/param4/param5

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60383266/python-reuse-functions-in-dash-callbacks/60405610#60405610), which might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Why not having 5 outputs directly ? Or if the number of components were to change dynamically, you could use a wrapper that contains all 'live-update-text-X' components and use a single output to update the wrapper's children.

Comment: Thanks @EricLavault, I think your answer raised a good path there, so basically you mean in ```@app.callback``` I can do something like: ```@app.callback(Output('live-update-text-1', 'children'),Output('live-update-text-2', 'children'),Output('live-update-text-3', 'children'),Output('live-update-text-4', 'children'),Output('live-update-text-5', 'children'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')```? That's something I am not aware of.

Comment: I am a bit confused on the wrapper contains all live-update-text-X though, do you mean we could return a list in the output and somehow parse the list in ```app.layout``` part of the code?

Comment: Ah never mind, I read a bit on the link @coralvanda provided and I think this might be what you are suggesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63255593/1528840, thanks a lot, I think now I can figure something out :)

Comment: @EricLavault thanks for your help so far, unfortunately I am still a bit stuck, I added in my attempt by following the example in the SO answer link I quoted above, but it seems my code still doesn't work, wondering if you could offer me a bit more hint to go further, thanks a lot.

Comment: Let's recap first : 1. Is there always 5 components to be updated or is the layout changing over time (with more or less of these components) ? 2. A callback is triggered every _<n_intervals>_, should this function update all of these components each time ?

Comment: @EricLavault thanks for your quick reply, to answer your questions: 1. 5 components would be updated all the time, eventually I might code a dynamic number of them and use MATCH but for now I just hard-coded 5 in app.layout. 2.  The function would iterate and update each of the 5 components (each components consists of a text block and a graph) at every single iteration (triggered every <n_intervals>. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the layout (at least the portion with the involved components) ?

Comment: Thanks @EricLavault, just added the portion of the layout code to main question, I mostly copied from example I had quoted in the question, however because I need to pass the variable 'name' to the updateGraphAndMetricForEach, that is where things were getting a little tricky for me. I don't have an input with id "param" however I am not sure if that's required since the variable is not controlled interactively by user but rather hard-coded into the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue I see is that you got multiple `dcc.Interval` (one per live component), but it's not neccessary since you only need one call per interval  for updating all the components.

Then, since all the elements to be updated are in the same container (I assume you put the `dbc.Col` in a `dbc.Row`) you can use a single output in your callback which updates the container children.

So in your layout you can do :

```
dcc.Interval(
    id='interval-component',
    interval=2*1000,  # in milliseconds
    n_intervals=0
),

dbc.Row(id="live-update-wrapper", children=[
    dbc.Col([
            html.Div(id=f'live-update-text-{param}'),
            dcc.Graph(id=f'live-update-graph-{param}'),
            html.Hr(),
        ],
        width={'size': 4, 'offset': 0, 'order': 1}
    ) for param in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
]),
```

And for the callback use the same logic (just grab the needed data and insert them accordingly along with the param id) :

```
@app.callback(
    Output("live-update-wrapper", "children"),
    Input("interval-component", "n_intervals"))
def updateGraphsAndData(n):
    return [
        dbc.Col([
                html.Div(id=f'live-update-text-{param}'),
                dcc.Graph(id=f'live-update-graph-{param}'),
                html.Hr(),
            ],
            width={'size': 4, 'offset': 0, 'order': 1}
        ) for param in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
]
```

Comment: Thanks so much Eric, now I start to understand what you meant by the wrapper, essentially you can even wrap the dbc.Col to be returned (I was more thinking a wrapper to just returning the actual plots and text). Appreciate all your help!

Comment: @AZhu Note that if you need smooth transitions for your graphs, you will need one output per _figure_ (cf. my first comment) + one per text component, but it can still be done using one single calllback.

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestions, if I understood you correctly you mean instead of having a ```Output("live-update-wrapper", "children"),``` you'll have something like ```Output(f"live-update-wrapper-{param}", "children")```?

Comment: No in this case (where you need each graph to transition smoothly), the wrapper is not an option because it will redraw that part of the layout. I meant one `Output(f'live-update-graph-{param}", "figure")` per graph, + one per text Div. And your callback would return a list corresponding to these outputs `[fig1, fig2, ..., fig5, txt1, txt2, ..., txt5]`.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get the return as a list to work (seems I have to do ```return fig1,fig2,fig3...txt1,...txt5``` rather than ```return [fig1,...fig5,txt1...txt5]``` so I ended up just return fig, txt but wrap them in ```for param in paramList:```, not sure if this is the most elegant way of doing things but for now this seems to work.