# How to pass arguments from main.py to a page in plotly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a page in plotly which has a call back like this -

```py
@dash.callback(
    Output("graph", "figure"),
    Input("checklist", "value"))
def update_line_chart(checklist):
    log = logparser.parse("D:\\Path\\openFoamParser\\simplefoam.log")
    data_pd_coeffs = log.getAbitrarySeriesCombination(**{"Cm": None, "Cd": None, "Cl": None, "Cl(f)": None, "Cl(r)": None})

    graph_params = {"yaxis_title": "Coeff - value", "xaxis_title": "Iterations", "width": 2000, "height": 800, "title": "Force Coeff Vs. Iterations"}
    fig = plotter.subPlot(1, 1, [(data_pd_coeffs, (1, 1))], graph_params)
    fig.for_each_xaxis(lambda axis: axis.title.update(font=dict(color='black', size=18)))
    fig.for_each_yaxis(lambda axis: axis.title.update(font=dict(color='black', size=18)))
    return fig
```

And I have a main.py where

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-f", help="path to openfoam file")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

Is there any way to pass these args in my main to my pages? I don't want to hardcode the paths in the plotly dash page.

Comment: Is it just about passing `args` to the plotly app though `main()`, or there is something about how plotly generates the app that prevents from having non hardcoded paths? Just asking to decide if I can answer.

Comment: i am not sure if we can pass args to the plotly app? i am not sure about this.

Comment: Understood, now I got the point, I thought it was instead just a matter of passing `args.f` to `main()`. I can't help, sorry. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70551224/python-dash-how-to-pass-parameters-in-app-callback) can help.