# How to write Dash callback simultaneously for a set of Buttons?

Tags: callback, output, plotly-dash

I have a set of buttons named `["Button_ORDER1", "Button_ORDER2", "Button_ORDER3", ....]` and so on which are dynamically created.

I want to write below callback for all these buttons simultaneously, presently written only for `Button_ORDER1`:

```py
@app.callback(
    [Output("Order_Processed_Item_List", "children")],
    [Input("Button_ORDER1", "n_clicks")]
)
def update_Order_Item_List(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks:
        e = orderItemList
    else:
        e = ""
    return [e]
```

Comment: You can use the logic and/or pattern matching callbacks as outlined it this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/70554893/2428887