# Multiple callbacks for single function

Tags: python, callback, plotly, plotly-dash

Based on the answer in this [Python - Reuse functions in Dash callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60383266/python-reuse-functions-in-dash-callbacks) I tried to use 2 callbacks calling the same function but then my dashboard gets stuck and have no errors showing.

```
@app.callback(
    [
        Output('errors-figure', 'figure'),
        Output('day', 'value'),
        Output('month', 'value'),
        Output('year', 'value'),
    ],
    [
        Input('update', 'n_intervals'),
    ],
    prevent_initial_call=False,
)
def initialize_dashboard(_, intervals):
    return callbacks.initialize_dashboard(_, intervals)

@app.callback(
    [
        Output('errors-figure', 'figure'),
    ],
    [
        Input('dbc-select1', 'value'),
    ],
    prevent_initial_call=False,
)
def initialize_dashboard1(_, intervals):
    return callbacks.initialize_dashboard(_, intervals)
```

I don't want to merge `Input('dbc-select1', 'value')` in the first callback because the 1st callback has many outputs I didn't show here and don't want them to be called again whenever I call the 2nd callback. What's wrong with what I am trying to do?

Comment: It looks like the first callback is calling itself in an infinite loop.

Comment: Turn debug mode on when you run the app. You have duplicate outputs ids.

Comment: @MackRaymond did that. Nothing unusual shown.

Comment: @coralvanda the callback alone without the 2nd runs normally

Comment: There should be an error about how you are trying to update Output('errors-figure', 'figure') from two different functions. Dash doesn't allow duplicated outputs. That will prevent the app from loading.

Comment: @MackRaymond should i initialize the output "errors-figure" on 1st callback without including it in the callback (the 1st callback is just for initializing the dashboard)

Comment: You will have to delete the second callback and move its input to the first callback. The first callback will then have multiple return statements depending on what you want to be updated. Example: https://medium.com/@draymo/some-tips-for-robust-dash-callbacks-4f97bcc4d471